# How to automatically update field values for all translated nodes

Tags: 7, entities

I have original node which is in english. Then I have another node which is a translation of the original node. Both of these nodes have the same image field. When I update the value - change the image for the original node and save it, the change doesn't apply to the second node (the translation of the original node). How do I make the field changes sync across the translated nodes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a *Synchronize Translations* module which is part of the [Internationalization Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) and which allows you to synchronize one (or more) fields across translations.

Once you have the module installed and enabled you can navigate to the content type in question and in the *Synchronize Translations-tab* check all fields you want to synchronize.

Check the Documentation here: [Synchronize translations](https://www.drupal.org/node/1279460).